# Storing a JWT on device to keep user logged in

Tags: java, android, security, jwt

I'm developing an android banking app and want users to stay logged in even after app is shut down. My idea to make this as secure as possible was to store a unique device id in the JWT and then extract the id from the token and compare it to the device id fetched from device at startup of app.

I would store the token in `SharedPreferences`, however, I just read that these device id's are not always unique due to people rooting they're phones. What would be the best solution? How can I be sure that the token I'm verifying at startup, is given to that user/device? I don't necessarily need to use device id's so any other secure option is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to have a persistable login session inside something as sensitive as banking app, but if you insist:

Use [SafetyNet Attestation API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html) for checking if the device you're running your app on is rooted and if it is, prevent the user from interacting. Once you did that just use regular `SharedPreferences` with `Mode.PRIVATE` and no one should be able to read this data outside of your app.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it for a while and agree with your first point. I came up with the idea to have an extra passcode which always needs to be entered on startup of app. I think this solves the security problem. This should also mean I can keep the user logged in. Since getting the JWT from `SharedPreferences` would still mean you need a passcode. Would like to hear your thoughts on this.